# Apache Ignite application deploy without rebalancing

Tags: java, spring, rest, ignite

I'm using Apache Ignite which is embedded in spring application(with tomcat) as a rest api server.

In my case, all node are server as data grid. and they serve specific data in memory. there is only one application each phisical server, and they are clustered by apache ignite.

but I have a probleam.

If I found a critical bug on that API, I need to fix and deploy.

So I have to deploy all application server. In that time, I should restart tomcat each server, then Rebalancing is occured. It makes worse performance to response during rebalancing, so sometimes My API will be not available.

My question is, should I always rebalance data whenever application is deployed?
If then, if the cluster is organized by thousands of nodes, should I go through thousands of rebalancing? Or Is there any other idea?

hope to your help, Thanks.

Comment: Do you have persistence configured?

Comment: @Denis no I haven't

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can configure a time interval, during which rebalancing won't be triggered automatically. [CacheConfiguration#rebalanceDelay](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/configuration/CacheConfiguration.html#getRebalanceDelay--) parameter is responsible for it.

This way rebalancing won't be triggered right after the nodes leave. Data will need to be rebalanced to the restarted node only.

If you don't want any rebalancing to happen at all, you can configure [native persistence](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/distributed-persistent-store) and set a [baseline topology](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/cluster-activation#section-baseline-topology). This way data will stay on nodes even after restart. And no data rebalancing will happen unless you change baseline topology manually. Note, that baseline topology feature is available since version 2.4. In previous versions you can use native persistence with rebalance delay instead.

Also some code changes may be performed without cluster restart, using [deployment SPI](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/deployment-spi#section-deploymentspi). But currently only [compute tasks](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/compute-grid) can be updated this way.

Comment: I read that docs, there is weird and couldn't understanding.   

The document said, "Note that the nodes that are planned for removal have to be stopped first. Otherwise, you will get an exception like Failed to remove nodes from baseline"  
But rebalancing is occured as soon as I restart my application(ignite is embedded). My nodes was set baseline

Comment: @HackingJ it means, that if you want to change the baseline topology of a running cluster, and the new baseline topology won't have some nodes, that are currently included into the baseline, then you should stop these nodes first.

Comment: @Denic Sorry, still couldn't understand. if I have 3nodes, and If I want to restart one node, How can I restart without rebalancing?

Comment: @HackingJ you don't need to change the baseline topology in this case. You just restart the node.

Comment: Hmm.. I guess I did wrong, Rebalance Event occured when I shutdown one node. below is my execute order. 1. control.sh --activate 2. control.sh --baseline set node1, node2, node3 3. service tomcat stop(In node3) I don't know what is wrong

Comment: @HackingJ did you configure persistence? How did you check, that rebalancing was happening?

Comment: Yes I configured, So my log is written : [initSize=2.0 GiB, maxSize=2.0 GiB, persistenceEnabled=true], and I listened EVT_CACHE_REBALANCE_STARTED event. when I stop node, the log is written : CACHE_REBALANCE_STARTED

Comment: @HackingJ please send your question about rebalancing with all your configuration to users list: http://apache-ignite-users.70518.x6.nabble.com

Comment: I sent question at users list. If you think it is not enough to check, reply here. I appreciate u